# Help! can't get simple compositing of render layers to work

Tags: rendering, node-editor, blur

I saw an answer to this exact same problem, but it was in 2.69. I tried it in 2.71 and it doesn't work. I've tried to blend the two objects using a simple color mix box and an alpha over box and neither would work. I've seen tuts using 2.6x and 2.5 and neither of them worked although a hybrid of the two got me to this simple attempt that I think I'm close to. I would like the blue color band on the boomerang to glow using a blur node.

thanks,
TP
[image: here is the compositing screen]

Comment: It doesn't look like either of your images have any transparency, so alpha over isn't going to do anything. Try making the sky transparent (how to do this depends on whether you are using BI or cycles).

Comment: OMG! Thank you. I have been chasing this like a hound dog for a week, scouring the web for tuts. and going through every one of them I thought would help, but all of them were pretty old (2.5 sometimes). I have posted this on another forum and loaded my files on them and struggled and struggled and no one noticed or indicated that I needed to have the images in a transparency. Aaahhhh!!!! Once again, thanks.